# Null property inside a service

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a service that receives 2 properties http and snack, when snack is called within a function, this is undefined but when printed on the console in the constructor it has a value.

this is my service:

```
import { throwError as observableThrowError, empty as observableEmpty } from 'rxjs';

import { HttpResponseBase } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AuthHttp } from './auth-http';
import { Snacks } from './snacks/snacks.service';

@Injectable()
export class BaseService {
    private _http: AuthHttp;
    private _snack: Snacks;

    constructor(http: AuthHttp, snack: Snacks) {
        this._http = http;
        this._snack = snack;
    }

    ...

    protected handleError(error: any) {
        // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response || error instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
            if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403 || error.status === 503) {
                return observableEmpty();
            }
            if (error.status === 400 || error.status === 404) {
                return observableThrowError(error);
            }
            const body = error || '';
            const err = body || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }

        if (error.error.message) {
            this._snack.error(error.error.message);
        }

        return observableThrowError(error.error.data);
    }
}
```

anyone knows why?

Comment: BTW, the constructor's body is redundant, and so are `_http` and `_snack`. You can declare `constructor(private http: AuthHttp, private snack: Snacks) {}`, and use `this.http` and `this.snack` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is `handleError` being called? Most likely it is being used in such a way that it makes `this` point back to the window object or something else. In this case change `handleError` to an arrow function as that will preserve `this` inside the body of the method.

```
protected handleError = (error:any) => { 
   /* unchanged body of method from your question */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're following the *Hero Service* example from the Angular documentation.

Change:

```js
   catchError(this.handleError)
```

To this:

```js
   catchError(this.handleError.bind(this))
   // or this
   catchError((err, ob) => this.handleError(err))
```

It is a bug in the code example, but the example works because they don't reference `this` in the example.